# How can I avoid images overlapping other elements using float,clear,position, etc. without using JS?

Tags: html, css

This is what I have at the moment, I also have the desirable outcome posted. Thanks for help!

```css
#red {
  background-color: #CC0000;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

#orange {
  background-color: #FF9900;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: white;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-top: 20x;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#yellow {
  background-color: #FFCC00;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: white;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-top: 20x;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#green {
  background-color: #009900;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: white;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-top: 20x;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#blue {
  background-color: #3366CC;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: white;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-top: 20x;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#violet {
  background-color: #9933CC;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: white;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-top: 20x;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.List {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  color: white;
  width: 240px;
  float: left;
  background-color: #494949;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 0;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="List">
    <p>Pick A Colour!</p>

    <ul>
      <div id="red">
        <li>
          <p>Red
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/MY9op5q.png" alt="arrow" title="arrow" />
          </p>
        </li>
      </div>

      <div id="orange">
        <li>
          <p>Orange
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/MY9op5q.png" alt="arrow" title="arrow" />
          </p>
        </li>
      </div>

      <div id="yellow">
        <li>
          <p>Yellow
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/MY9op5q.png" alt="arrow" title="arrow" />
          </p>
        </li>
      </div>

      <div id="green">
        <li>
          <p>Green
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/MY9op5q.png" alt="arrow" title="arrow" />
          </p>
        </li>
      </div>

      <div id="blue">
        <li>
          <p>Blue
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/MY9op5q.png" alt="arrow" title="arrow" />
          </p>
        </li>
      </div>

      <div id="violet">
        <li>
          <p>Violet
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/MY9op5q.png" alt="arrow" title="arrow" />
          </p>
        </li>
      </div>

    </ul>
  </div>
```

Desired outcome:

[image]

I'm new to the community and if I did something wrong in asking please tell me. Thanks for your future help!

Comment: FYI the only valid child of `ul` is `li`. You have `div`'s.

Comment: I see, I'm new to HTML and CSS stuff do I make some noob mistakes. Thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can vastly reduce the amount of code you need to produce this layout. There is no need to rewrite the same styles multiple times. CSS can be reused across multiple elements. Your HTML could be reduced too.

```css
.List {
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
  color: white;
  width: 240px;
  background-color: #494949;
}

.List li {
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background: url(http://i.imgur.com/MY9op5q.png) no-repeat right center;
}

.List ul {
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#red {
  background-color: #CC0000;
}

#orange {
  background-color: #FF9900;
}

#yellow {
  background-color: #FFCC00;
}

#green {
  background-color: #009900;
}

#blue {
  background-color: #3366CC;
}

#violet {
  background-color: #9933CC;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="List">
    <p> Pick A Colour! </p>
    <ul>
      <li id="red">
        Red
      </li>
      <li id="orange">
        Orange
      </li>
      <li id="yellow">
        Yellow
      </li>
      <li id="green">
        Green
      </li>
      <li id="blue">
        Blue
      </li>
      <li id="violet">
        Violet
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: I was writting an answer, but yours is highly better... :-)

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to try this out!